# Order Of Properties In Hash Table

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm trying to create a custom object from a hash table to pipe to Export-Csv.
However the properties are all out of order when I create the csv file.
I have put comments below to show the order.

```
function CreateStatusCustomObject
{
    param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][Hashtable]$Values)

    $statusCustomObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject        

    foreach($value in $Values.GetEnumerator())
    {
        $statusCustomObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $value.Name -Value $value.Value
    }

    return $statusCustomObject
}

$Cec = 'a'
$DnsServer = 'b'
$subnetInfoCidr = 'c'
$oldServerRefreshIntervalValue = 'd'
$anotherProperty = 'e'

$statusCustomObject = CreateStatusCustomObject @{Cec = $Cec; #2
                                                DnsServer = $DnsServer; #5
                                                Cidr = $subnetInfoCidr; #1
                                                OldServerRefreshIntervalValue = $oldServerRefreshIntervalValue;#3
                                                AnotherProperty = $anotherProperty} #4
```

How can I force the order to be what it is in the hash table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `[ordered]` type accelerator. I think this was introduced in PowerShell v3.

In your case, this should do the trick:

```
$statusCustomObject = CreateStatusCustomObject [ordered]@{Cec = $Cec;
                                                          DnsServer = $DnsServer;
                                                          Cidr = $subnetInfoCidr;
                                                          OldServerRefreshIntervalValue = $oldServerRefreshIntervalValue;
                                                          AnotherProperty = $anotherProperty}
```

Behind the scenes, the object created is actually an OrderedDictionary.

Since this is relying on PowerShell 3 anyway, you could also create you object directly (and skip the function... assuming there is a specific reason for it that I'm missing) like this:

```
$statusCustomObject = [pscustomobject]@{
    Cec = $Cec
    DnsServer = $DnsServer
    Cidr = $subnetInfoCidr
    OldServerRefreshIntervalValue = $oldServerRefreshIntervalValue
    AnotherProperty = $anotherProperty
}
```

The result should be in the right order, but if not you can combine accelerators (e.g. `[pscustomobject][ordered]@{}`)

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem with a pattern like below.

**CODE**

```
#data

$listofitems = @()

$myDataItem = [PSCustomOBject]@{
    Cec = 'a'
    DnsServer = 'b'
    subnetInfoCidr = 'c'
    oldServerRefreshIntervalValue = 'd'
    anotherProperty = 'e'
}

$listofitems += $myDataItem

$myDataItem = [PSCustomOBject]@{
    Cec = 'a1'
    DnsServer = 'b1'
    subnetInfoCidr = 'c1'
    oldServerRefreshIntervalValue = 'd1'
    anotherProperty = 'e1'
}

$listofitems += $myDataItem

cls
Write-Output "all properties"
$listofitems | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

Write-Output "`r`nproperties in my own order"
$listofitems | Select oldServerRefreshIntervalValue, DnsServer | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Output**

```
all properties
"Cec","DnsServer","subnetInfoCidr","oldServerRefreshIntervalValue","anotherProperty"
"a","b","c","d","e"
"a1","b1","c1","d1","e1"

properties in my own order
"oldServerRefreshIntervalValue","DnsServer"
"d","b"
"d1","b1"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sort into your function too, like this :

```
function CreateStatusCustomObject
{
    param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][Hashtable]$Values)

   $statusCustomObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject

   $Values.Keys | sort -CaseSensitive | %{
   $key=$_;$value=$Values[$_];
   $statusCustomObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $key -Value $value
   }

    return $statusCustomObject
}
```